# Magento 2.2.5 coupon codes not working

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.2.5, coupon-codes

I have added several cart price rules to magento but every time i enter the code to a shopping cart i get the error that the couponcode is not valid.

How can this be solved?

Comment: is it enterprise version?

Comment: did you create them correctly? website-scope is the first issue taht comes to my mind

Comment: you can follow How to Setup Promotions / Cart Price Rule in Magento 2 (https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-a-cart-price-rule-in-magento-2.htm)   as reference.

Comment: It is Version 2.2.5 CE. I added the website scope correctly by following the mageplaza tutorial from https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-a-cart-price-rule-in-magento-2.html But i keep getting the error

Comment: Check the settings , expire date , prioritys , conditions .

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145539)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145539)